# Get Paypal Subscription status per cronjob problem

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have successfully set up paypal subscriptions, they work via sandbox without problems.
However, I want to query daily the status of customers ( ACTIVE, SUSPENDED, CANCELLED, EXPIRED ...), but found no complete and understandable documentation for Paypal webhooks and unfortunately did not get it implemented.
I found this tutorial and implemented successfully: https://www.stacklounge.de/6328/tutorial-integrate-paypal-subscription-javascript-complete.

```
function paypal_subscription_get_status($subscriptionid, $accesstoken)
{
  // client subscription ID, example ID from customer: I-WB34K81SW1XX
  if(empty($subscriptionid) || empty($accesstoken))
  {
    return;
  }
  
  $headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$accesstoken, 
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ];
  
  $ch = curl_init();
  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/".$subscriptionid);
  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/".$subscriptionid); // LIVE
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); // important: GET not POST, otherwise error
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  // $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // 200

  if(curl_errno($ch)) 
  {
    var_dump( 'ERROR: '.curl_error($ch) );
  }

  $json = json_decode($response);
  
  /*
  APPROVAL_PENDING. The subscription is created but not yet approved by the buyer.
  APPROVED. The buyer has approved the subscription.
  ACTIVE. The subscription is active.
  SUSPENDED. The subscription is suspended.
  CANCELLED. The subscription is cancelled.
  EXPIRED. The subscription is expired.
  */
  
  // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get
  $subscription_status = $json->status;
  
  return $subscription_status;
}
```

With this I can now check the status via cronjob regularly, it works fine.

My question, does anyone know how I can use this to get back not only the status but possibly more data, for example the custom_id and the total?

(If someone knows a good paypal documentation for webhooks, I'll gladly take it. I know the outdated SDK and Paypal's own, they are unfortunately incomplete ...).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Change your conceptual understanding of subscriptions.

Whether there is an active PayPal subscription profile determines whether there is a scheduled future charge which *might* (or might not) succeed. This information is of little practical value.

Instead, track the status in your own system. Register a webhook listener for the event `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`.  Every time you receive this event, updated your own system's status with when the subscription is good through. If you don't receive a new PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED event in time, the subscription has lapsed.

Comment: Thx. I would like to accept this, but without appropriate documentation for webhooks at Paypal is now unfortunately not possible at all. I will switch to Stripe. You know.

Comment: Webhook event names for subscriptions are documented at https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions , but the only important one is `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`

Comment: I know where they are named. 
And I tried all via sandbox and developer account. I do not get any notices from webhooks, although I activated all and have a webhook point working in my host... Many people notice that, you know. 
I can't get a solution and I do not find anywhere a good solid documentation, and internet is full about that, you know. There is no working (php) script anywhere! So, I switch to stripe, they have a big, complete doc and even paypal subscription included (php).